# Unable to send signinPolicy inside the Query Params in Azure AD B2C using React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, msal-react

I have been trying to integrate my Azure AD B2C Auth Service on frontend using React JS. The problem that I am facing is that I am unable to pass a query params inside the request URL and that is why, the signInPolicy (p) is being passed as null. I do not know what I am doing wrong. Also tried different solutions from the Internet. Currently, I have been using @azure/msal-react npm package. My configuration code and the issue that I am facing is listed down:

```
// inside Config.js

export const msalConfig = {
auth: {
    authority:
        `https://{TENANT_SUB_DOMAIN}.b2clogin.com/{TENANT_OR_DOMAIN_NAME}/B2C_1_signupsignin`,
    clientId: "MY_CLIENT_ID",
    signInPolicy: "B2C_1_signupsignin",
    prompt: "login",
    knownAuthorities: ["checkappb2c.b2clogin.com"],
    redirectUri: 'https%3A%2F%2Fa{MY_APP_NAME}-alpha.azurewebsites.net',
    validateAuthority: false,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000'
},
cache: {
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
    },

}

export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["User.Read"],
    extraQueryParameters: {signInPolicy: 'B2C_1_signupsignin', p : 'B2C_1_signupsignin'}
};

// inside App.js

const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
const [graphData, setGraphData] = useState(null);

function RequestProfileData() {
    // Silently acquires an access token which is then attached to a request for MS Graph data
    instance.acquireTokenSilent({
        ...loginRequest,
        account: accounts[0]
    }).then((response) => {
        callMsGraph(response.accessToken).then(response => setGraphData(response));
    });
}
```

// The Issue that I am facing:[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need p parameter, you either have policy in the path or the p parameter. Yours is in the path.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#send-authentication-requests

User.read is an invalid scope. Create your own scope and pass it in.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-spa-app#step-2-register-your-spa-and-api

You can’t call Graph API with B2C token, so your fetch profile code will not work.

Comment: After doing above changes, I have been facing CORS issue although I have also set my https://localhost:/3000 url inside Cors policy at the backend

Comment: Create a new post if this issue is solved with full details of the new problem.